# Matplotlib.pyplot.subplots() не отображает графики seaborn на разных сетках

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Есть непрерывная переменная `df_train_tr['TransactionAmt']`, хочу построить плотность распределения переменной в изначальном формате и после применения функции `log`.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(11, 5), sharey=True)
plt.style.use('classic')
fig.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:white')

ax[0]= sns.distplot(df_train_tr[df_train_tr['TransactionAmt'] <= 1000]['TransactionAmt'])
ax[0].set_xlabel('TransactionAmt', fontsize=16)
ax[0].set_title('Transaction Value distibution')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Probability', fontsize=16)
ax[0].axis(xmin=0)

ax[1] = sns.distplot(np.log(df_train_tr[df_train_tr['TransactionAmt'] <= 1000]['TransactionAmt']))
ax[1].set_xlabel('TransactionAmt', fontsize=16)
ax[1].set_title('Transaction Value distibution')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Probability', fontsize=16)
ax[1].axis(xmin=0)

plt.show()
```

[image: 2 графика с seaborn]
 Данный код рисует все на одном графике и, самое интересное, переменная `ax` состоит из двух одинаковых объектов

```
[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f8147bf6978>,
 <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f8147bf6978>],
          dtype=object)
```

Хотя до исполнения строчек с `ax[0]` и `ax[1]` объекты разные

```
[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f8147faeef0>
 <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f8147f37160>]
```

Переписал, используя вместо `sns.distplot()` `plt.hist()`

```
ax[0].hist(df_train_tr[df_train_tr['TransactionAmt'] <= 1000]['TransactionAmt'])
#ax[0]= sns.distplot(df_train_tr[df_train_tr['TransactionAmt'] <= 1000]['TransactionAmt'])
ax[0].set_xlabel('TransactionAmt', fontsize=16)
ax[0].set_title('Transaction Value distibution')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Probability', fontsize=16)
ax[0].axis(xmin=0)

ax[1].hist(np.log(df_train_tr[df_train_tr['TransactionAmt'] <= 1000]['TransactionAmt']))
#ax[1] = sns.distplot(np.log(df_train_tr[df_train_tr['TransactionAmt'] <= 1000]['TransactionAmt']))
ax[1].set_xlabel('TransactionAmt', fontsize=16)
ax[1].set_title('Transaction Value distibution')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Probability', fontsize=16)
ax[1].axis(xmin=0)

plt.show()
```

И получил то, что хотел (y_axis - sic!)

Можно ли переписать код, чтобы получить второй вариант, но используя `Seaborn`?

[image: 2 графика с plt.hist()]

Comment: в методе `ax[0]= sns.distplot(df_train_tr[df_train_tr['TransactionAmt'] <= 1000]['TransactionAmt'])` gjghj,eqnt добавить параметр `ax=ax[0]`. То есть, `ax[0]= sns.distplot(df_train_tr[df_train_tr['TransactionAmt'] <= 1000]['TransactionAmt'], ax=ax[0])`  для первого subplot и по аналогии (ax=ax[1]) - для второго.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Укажите явно axis, с которой работаете:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(11, 5), sharey=True)
plt.style.use('classic')
fig.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:white')
x = np.random.randn(100)

ax=axs[0]
ax= sns.distplot(x, ax=ax) # <-- здесь
ax.set_xlabel('TransactionAmt', fontsize=16)
ax.set_title('Transaction Value distibution')
ax.set_ylabel('Probability', fontsize=16)
ax.axis(xmin=0)

ax=axs[1]
ax = sns.distplot(np.log(abs(x)), ax=ax, hist=False) # здесь я еще и гистограмму
                                                     # отключил. для наглядности
ax.set_xlabel('TransactionAmt', fontsize=16)
ax.set_title('Transaction Value distibution')
ax.set_ylabel('Probability', fontsize=16)
ax.axis(xmin=0)

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, помогло, спасибо!